# How to reconfigure a project

Tags: linux, configure, autotools, anjuta

ALL,

I have a project on GitHub which is an application I'm still developing.

On Linux I'm using Anjuta as an IDE to generate the Makefile and build it.

The problem I'm facing is that I just build myself a newer machine with the newer set of autotools and now the project fails to build because its Makefile is set to use the older version.

In particular `make` complains about using `aclocal version 1.15` and the newer box have `aclocal version 1.16`.

What would be the process of making the code build I presume I need to run some kind of reconfiguration tool to make the configure aware of the upgrade. I just don't know how and what.

Also, if someone can help on what files needs to be in the source control so that every single time I update everything will be regenerated automatically.

TIA!!

Comment: If you want to update an Autotools project to use different versions of some of the Autotools components, then you must rebuild the autotooling.  I have no idea whether Ajunta has a mechanism for that, but for an ordinary Autotools project, the best bet is usually to change to the project source directory and run `autoreconf -if`.  Sometimes this requires updates to `configure.ac` or other build-system components.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thank you. That worked. It compiles now.  Now what files should be in the Git? I initially put everything in there, but it looks like it is a mistake...

Comment: There is a diversity of opinion about that, but my firm position is that everything that's actually part of the project and that is left behind by `make distclean` should go into source control.  By "actually part of the project" I mean to exclude things like editor backup files and random extraneous files that get dropped into the source tree.  Including files such as `configure` and `Makefile.in`, which are Autotools outputs, supports the Autotools objective that someone who just wants to build the project doesn't need to have a copy of the autotools installed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thank you. I will just do the same.